# Сохранение состояния терминала VS Code

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code

работаю над проектом в котором надо держать 4-5 терминалов в работе: Node, Electron, Docker, виртуальный сервер и консоль сборки для GO. После перезапуска VS Code каждый раз все терминалы находятся в одной папке, плюс у них стираются команды, которые вводились. Можно ли как-то запоминать состояния каждого терминала? Чтобы после открытия они хотя бы открывались в нужных папках? Заранее всем огромное спасибо.

Comment: Ответ с английского SO вас не устраивает? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312095/save-terminal-tabs-to-saved-workspace-vscode

Comment: @GeneErbin Таки полностью устраивает! Совершенно то, что мне нужно! Но я не смог его сам найти, сколько не гуглил...  Спасибо

Comment: Если англоязычная версия хороша, то ее можно перенести сюда, предварительно переведя)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существовал плагин "Terminal Settings Synchronizer" для VS Code(я сейчас не смог найти его). Оно позволяет сохранять и восстанавливать состояние терминала, включая историю команд, путь к текущей директории и настройки терминала. Также расширение позволяет синхронизировать эти настройки с удаленным хранилищем, таким как GitHub Gist.

Но тем не менее вы можете сохранять состояние каждого терминала вручную. Например, можете запускать каждый терминал в отдельной вкладке и сохранять состояние каждой вкладки как профиль. В будущем вы можете использовать этот профиль для восстановления состояния терминала. Это может быть немного более ручным, но это должно решить вашу проблему.

помимо [решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312095/save-terminal-tabs-to-saved-workspace-vscode), описанное на англоязычной , вот еще пару плагинов для VS Code, которые могут помочь вам сохранять состояние терминала:

- "Terminal session manager": это расширение позволяет сохранять сессии терминала и восстанавливать их позже.
- "Terminal Tabs": это расширение добавляет возможность работы с несколькими терминалами в одной вкладке, с возможностью именования и сохранения сессий.
  -"Multi-command": расширение позволяет запускать несколько команд одновременно в терминале, а также сохранять и восстанавливать историю команд.